# Can't store navigator.geolocation data in useffect, with a usestate

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have a problem, I want to store latitude and longitude from `navigator.geolocation` in a `useEffect` before the render, with an empty array but when I `console.log` my result it displays `null`.

Here is the part concerned.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const [userPos, setUserPos] = useState({lat: null, long: null})

 useEffect(() => {
      navigator.geolocation.getcurrentposition((pos) =>{
          console.log(pos.coords.latitude + " " + pos.coords.longitude) // display VALUE
          setUserPos({ 
                lat: pos.coords.latitude,
                long: pos.coords.longitude,
           }) // store data in usestate
          console.log(userPos) // Display Null
     }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
     },options);
    }
  })
 }, [])
```

So why, when I log `pos.coords` in the `useEffect` I have the value but not when I log my state. Any ideas?

Comment: Because react doesn't re-render your hook half way through. It re-renders when the state changes after the function is done.

Comment: @Dominik and how can i store the data in the first render

Comment: I added an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React can't re-render your function half way through. Instead create a new variable that you pass to your set function and use it after. Do note that `userPos` will be available to you outside the `useEffect` after re-render. So the new variable is only useful to you within the same `useEffect` function.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const [userPos, setUserPos] = useState({lat: null, long: null})

 useEffect(() => {
      navigator.geolocation.getcurrentposition((pos) =>{
          console.log(pos.coords.latitude + " " + pos.coords.longitude) // display VALUE
          const newUserPos = { 
                lat: pos.coords.latitude,
                long: pos.coords.longitude,
           };
          setUserPos(newUserPos) // store data in usestate
          console.log(newUserPos) // Display your values
     }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
     },options);
    }
  })
 }, [])
```